# Подскажите, как правильно написать фразу (прыгнуть - выпрыгнуть)

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нет ли ошибки во фразе: "Вчера ночью мужчина прыгнул из окна в лужу"? Или будет правильно сказать: "Вчера ночью мужчина выпрыгнул из окна в лужу"?

Или допустимы оба варианта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустимы оба.

С вышки пловец прыгает? Угу. А почему не спрыгивает?

Так и из окна можно прыгнуть и выпрыгнуть.

---

[ПРЫГАТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (нам подойдёт уже и первое значение этой многозначной лексемы) Делать прыжок (прыжки), передвигаться прыжком (прыжками). *П. на одной ноге. **П.** вверх, **вниз**.*, но если покажется мало, можно заглянуть по ссылочке.

Пример употребления:

[Мужчина прыгнул из окна по приказу таинственных голосов](https://megapolisonline.ru/muzhchina-prygnul-iz-okna-po-prikazu-tainstvennyh-golosov/)

Comment: Приказ голосов звучал "прыгай", а не "выпрыгни/выбросись". А можно ли "_выпрыгнуть_ в лужу", будь то из окна или из машины?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы!